# Write the activemq log in windows event log

Tags: windows, logging, activemq-classic

Does anyone know how to write the log of activeMQ  as an event to the windows event log (or whether it's even possible)?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it but the ActiveMQ logging is done via slf4j and by default it uses log4j which does seem to have a way to configure on Windows to write into the event logs.

There some API documentation [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/nt/NTEventLogAppender.html) but this approach does require you to place some DLLs on the system.  There seems to be some other options using JNA which is over [here](https://github.com/dblock/log4jna).

The short answer is that the Broker doesn't support this directly but given the logging is configurable you should be able to accomplish it.

Comment: i try the solution of NTEventLogAppender but it doesn't work

Comment: Try the alternate solution with JNA and see if that works.  You need to provide more info for people to help you, "It doesn't work" is of no real use